# Is there a standard solution for Gauss elimination in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

Is there somewhere in the cosmos of `scipy/numpy/...` a standard method for Gauss-elimination of a matrix?

One finds many snippets via google, but I would prefer to use "trusted" modules if possible.

Comment: Are you looking for Gaussian elimination especially, or any way of solving systems of linear equations/inverting matrices/...?

Comment: No I need gaussian elimination only. The reason for that is, I have systems of `N` equations with rank `r<N` and want to extract `r` equations from them, still including the full information.

Comment: You could have a look here http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Comment: Thanks Mr E, but I would like to avoid the conversion to symbolic objects if possible. It would be nice to have something explicitly for arrays (of floats), in the best case something which becomes exact for arrays of integers.

Comment: I wrote my own [here](http://ricardianambivalence.com/2012/10/20/pure-python-gauss-jordan-solve-ax-b-invert-a/)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I finally found, that it can be done using **LU decomposition**. Here the **U** matrix represents the reduced form of the linear system.

```
from numpy import array
from scipy.linalg import lu

a = array([[2.,4.,4.,4.],[1.,2.,3.,3.],[1.,2.,2.,2.],[1.,4.,3.,4.]])

pl, u = lu(a, permute_l=True)
```

Then `u` reads

```
array([[ 2.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Depending on the solvability of the system this matrix has an upper triangular or trapezoidal structure. In the above case a line of zeros arises, as the matrix has only rank `3`.

Comment: [see this example](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2014/04/gaussian-elimination-using-lu.html)

Comment: @alvas a decomposition of a matrix into a product of a lower and an upper triangular matrix, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Comment: The U factor need not to be in row-echelon form in Lapack. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891334/is-the-u-factor-in-lu-decomposition-for-rectangular-matrices-always-in-row-echel

Answer (score 6):

One function that can be worth checking is `_remove_redundancy`, if you wish to remove repeated or redundant equations:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

a = np.array([[1.,1.,1.,1.],
              [0.,0.,0.,1.],
              [0.,0.,0.,2.],
              [0.,0.,0.,3.]])
print(scipy.optimize._remove_redundancy._remove_redundancy(a, np.zeros_like(a[:, 0]))[0])
```

which gives:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 3.]]
```

As a note to @flonk answer, using a LU decomposition might not always give the desired reduced row matrix. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg

a = np.array([[1.,1.,1.,1.],
              [0.,0.,0.,1.],
              [0.,0.,0.,2.],
              [0.,0.,0.,3.]])

_,_, u = scipy.linalg.lu(a)
print(u)
```

gives the same matrix:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 3.]]
```

even though the last 3 rows are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the symbolic mathematics python library `sympy`

```
import sympy as sp

m = sp.Matrix([[1,2,1],
           [-2,-3,1],
           [3,5,0]])

m_rref, pivots = m.rref() # Compute reduced row echelon form (rref).

print(m_rref, pivots)
```

This will output the matrix in reduced echelon form, as well as a list of the pivot columns

```
Matrix([[1, 0, -5],
        [0, 1,  3],
        [0, 0,  0]])

(0, 1)
```