# Gauss and Gauss Jordan in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Why doesn't there exist a library that implements the Gauss or Gauss Jordan method directly, that is, some module in numpy or sympy that comes by default? Or does it exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [15638650](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638650)

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it exists and it's in sympy  [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/matrices/matrices.html#MatrixBase.gauss_jordan_solve)