# Efficient Implementation of Gaussian Elimination in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am working on converting some scientific computing code from Fortran to Python (and perhaps later to Julia). I understand that Fortran is usually faster than Python especially when dealing with loops. But there are benefits as well to using Python over Fortran.

My goal in converting this code is not to retain all the speed of Fortran, but hopefully stay within a factor of 10 by using JAX and JIT.

One clever thing that I have found in the Fortran code is a method for computing matrix multiplication with inverted matrices. Some terms that appear in solving the physical-phenomena are

[image: \xi_1 = B_1^{-1}G_1]

[image: E_1 = - B_1^{-1} D_1]

[image: x = -B_1^{-1} X]

We can see that [image: B_1^{-1}] is repeatedly multiplied with other matrices. So what is done in the Fortran code is something like a matrix stacking(?), followed by Gaussian elimination. The matrices [image: B_1], [image: D_1], [image: X], [image: G_1] are horizontally concatenated. Then Gaussian elimination is performed to transform [image: B_1] into the identity matrix, [image: I].

The row operations performed to change [image: B_1] --> [image: I], transform the other matrices as well:

[image: D_1] -->
[image: B_1^{-1}D_1]

[image: X] -->
[image: B_1^{-1}X]

[image: G_1] -->
[image: B_1^{-1}G_1]

[image: MatrixConcatenation]

Is this an efficient method to perform the matrix algebra? The dimensions of these matrices are between 1x1 and 12x12 depending on the problem being solved.

Comment: Thanks. I googled the title and I do not see the linked question in the google results. There are many basic implementations of Gaussian elimination in python, but no standard library was being pointed to. I also searched this site with the title and it doesn't produce that result.

Comment: My original post was also asking for a standard method of efficient Gaussian elimination (which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638650/is-there-a-standard-solution-for-gauss-elimination-in-python). But I have edited the question just to understand, gain insight or feedback on this specific method of matrix algebra.