# Why isn't there a "Gaussian Elimination" function in languages such as Julia or NumPy/Python?

Tags: numpy, julia, linear-algebra

Why isn't there a Gaussian Elimination function in packages such as NumPy or Julia?

- I know about LU decomposition
- I know about the \ (backslash) operator

I still think it would be nice to perform Gaussian Elimination. For example, the following matrix:

```
[
4 -1 1 0
1  1 0 1
]
```

Comment: what do you want it for that `\` doesn't give you?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638650/is-there-a-standard-solution-for-gauss-elimination-in-python) answer your question?

Comment: Not quite because I'd still have to reduce the diagonal to 1s and then eliminate everything above the diagonal.

Comment: Did you read ALL the answers and not just the first one? The last does that.

Comment: Fair call. The last one does answer it. I read the first two (not just the first one), but I skipped out before the third. My bad. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Apples14 there **is** a clear answer to this question in the case of Julia — although useful for pedagogy "`rref` has no use in real numerical coding" ([JuliaLang/Julia#9804](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9804#issuecomment-77515283)); there are better methods.  It does exist though: in the package [RowEchelon.jl](https://github.com/blegat/RowEchelon.jl).

Answer (score 3):

We can solve it with the backslash by:

```
[
4 -1
1  1
] \ [
1 0
0 1
]
```

The result will be the right two columns of the RREFed matrix (the left two columns will be the 2x2 identity, but the result of this code won't show the left two columns).

The general rule is for an m x n matrix, put m columns on the left side of the backslash, and the remaining n - m columns on the right. So if we wanted to perform Gaussian Elimination on the following matrix:

```
[
1 2 7 0 0 0
2 8 0 1 0 0
2 4 1 0 1 0
2 2 3 0 0 1
]
```

We would do

```
A = [
1 2 7 0
2 8 0 1
2 4 1 0
2 2 3 0
]
B = [
0 0
0 0
1 0
0 1
]
x = A \ B
```

And just as before, it will give us the resulting rightmost n - m columns of the RREFed matrix, and you assume the left m (which it does not show) are the m x m identity matrix.

Lastly, if we want to check how good our answer is (i.e. determine if it's exact or least squares), we can now run

```
norm(A * x - B)
```

to see how close we are to the 0 matrix.